# Force version increment without locking table in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Can NHibernate somehow force a version number increment without locking the table?

I know I can do this to force a version number increment:

```
session.Lock(myEntity, LockMode.Force);
```

But the problem is that this will also aquire a physical lock on the table row, which causes big concurrency issues in my application.

In the Java Hibernate world, this seems to be possible:

```
session.lock(myEntity, LockMode.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
```

NHibernate's `LockMode.Force` appears to be equivalent to Hibernate's `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`, with no equivalent to `LockMode.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`.

Comparing the documention of the Java and .NET version, there seem to be several LockModes missing in NHibernate that exist in Hibernate. 
Any ideas how to deal with that limitation?

Answer (score 0):

If you use numeric version property you can just assign it to 0 and NHibernate will auto increment it for you.

Comment: This isn't exactly the same as LockMode.Force. Although assigning 0 to version increment it, the change will go through as a full update on the entity including all of its fields. session.Lock(...Force) will execute an update of the version field only.